# Как получить кол-во участников в голосовых каналах discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я использую discord.py 2.1.1 и мне необходимо узнать как получить число которое будет обозначать кол-во человек которые находятся в голосовых каналах на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать этот способ, чтобы вывести количество человек во всех голосовых каналах сервера.

```
voice_members = set()

guild = … # Нужный сервер

for voice in guild.voice_channels:
    for member in voice.members:
        voice_members.add(member.id)

print(len(voice_members))
```